# Career ads links have port 80 in URL 

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

Any particular reason why the job listing ads on stackoverflow include port 80 in the URL?  Seems like it could be removed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, thanks for pointing that out. We've cleaned that up.